# Run in Release mode then detach does not increase performance

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

If I run my program using F5 in Release mode then click Detach All from the debugging menu, my program still slow in compare to if I run it directly using Ctrl+F5. Why does this happen? Should not it work as speed as if I run it using Ctrl+F5 from the beginning because no debugging is happening any more?

Comment: Your assumption that the debugger makes a program slow is not accurate.  You'd have to create a *lot* of threads or throw tens of thousands of exceptions per second.  So not seeing any difference when you detach is entirely normal.  Why it is slow when you start with it attached requires a visit to a site where psychics give free advice, there is no cue left in your question.  Although they probably exclaim "you're actually debugging the Debug build" and call it a day :)

Comment: Thanks, I have conclude from you comment that my problem is in the slowness of the attached mode not in the difference. I would search for this by myself because I have seen many posts on this issue before.. Have a nice day :)